# nested partial View calling HttpPost method 2 times

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have seen this question being asked few times here , but solution I saw are not generic , they are related to their specific code ..

I need to rectify the Work done by previous developer , the flow of ajax calls are wrong in code

In my Situation I have views like :

```
1.Index (Main View)
2.ParentCategoryList (partial View inside Index)
3. AddChild (partial View inside ParentCategoryList )
4. childCategorytree  (Seperate View )
```

Problem is that from 2nd nested View (AddChild ) , whhen i click on save button ,httpost method is calling twice

My Index View

```
<div>

            <div class="content" id="divparent">
            </div>

            <div class="content" id="dvChild">
            </div>


</div>
```

its script

```
@section scripts{


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('document').ready(function () {


            //------------
            $.get('@Url.Action("ParentCategoryList", "List")', function (data) {
                $("#divparent").html("");
                $("#divparent").html(data);

            });

        })



        function addnewchild(url) {

            $.get(url, function (data) {
                $("#dvChild").html("");
                $("#dvChild").html(data);

            });
        }


    </script>

}
```

2. First Partial View inside Index (ParentCategoryList.cshtml)

   ```
       @foreach (Bmsa.UI.Models.ListsResultModel  data in Model)
       {
           <tr> <td><a onclick="addnewchild('@Url.Action("AddChild",   
       "List", new { id = @data.listID })')" >
                   </a> </td></tr> }  </tbody> </table>
   ```
3. 2nd Nested Partial View inside ParentCategoryList

   ```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddChild", "List", new AjaxOptions
   {

   HttpMethod = "POST",
   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
   UpdateTargetId = "dvChild"
   }))
           {
           <div > <input type="submit" value="Save" /></p></div>}
   ```

and Controller methods

```
    public ActionResult ParentCategoryList()
     {
        //Code 
        return PartialView("ParentCategoryList", categoryList); }
```

//GET Operation to Load this View

```
      public ActionResult AddChild(int id)
      {
        ViewBag.ParentID = id;
        ListsAddModel addchild = new ListsAddModel();
        addchild.parentListId = id;
        return PartialView("AddChild", addchild);
      }


  [HttpPost] (**this method is calling twice--this is the problem** )
    public ActionResult AddChild(ListsAddModel model,int id)
    {

   //Code
        return RedirectToAction ("ChildCategoryListTree", new { id = model.parentListId });
    }
```

4. and childCategorytree Partial view (also blank one)

I am not able to prevent this method to called twice . I tried e.preventDefault() in $.ajax call , but it is not working ...

I have tried to minimise the code , I think the problem is in RedirectToAction , but I am not sure

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: There is not a lot here making sense, and you mix of jquery.ajax and `Ajax.BeginForm()` makes it difficult to understand what your trying to do. Your `AddChild()` method is being called by ajax but the method contains a parameter `ListsAddModel model` which will always be a new instance of `ListsAddModel` (and using ` new { id = model.parentListId }` would always be the equivalent of calling `new { id = 0 }`), but more importantly it contains a `return RedirectToAction()` but ajax calls never redirect (the whole purpose of ajax is to stay on the same page)

Comment: Actually this work is done by a previous Dev , I know the flow is somewhat wrong

Comment: IS there possibility to make correction in this flow , Or do I have to rewrite the flow again ?

Comment: You should certainly make some changes, but I cannot follow what your trying to do. Why do you have a `<a>` element that calls your `AddChild()` method (and it does not even have any display text) and a `Ajax.BeginForm()` that also calls you `AddChild()` method?

Comment: ok , let me study the code behaviour more ,  will get back to you

Comment: actually there are 3 addchild Method , Get and Post one , First one will load the partial View inside upper view , and Second will perform post save operation from Addchild view , i have update the Controller methods in post

Comment: sorry 2 addchild methods